# Non-OS Specific FD(File Descriptor) for C/C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, asynchronous, file-io, network-programming

Linux is also treated as a file, a network socket. but, Windows is not.
and common files and network sockets treated as "FD".
if the code should not rely on the operating system, how should write?

i think it like below..

```
#ifndef INVALID_SOCKET
#define INVALID_SOCKET (-1)
#endif

class Descriptor {
private:
   int m_fd;

public:
   Descriptor() : m_fd(INVALID_SOCKET) { }
   virtual ~Descriptor() { this->close(); }
   virtual bool isValid();
   virtual bool close() = 0;
   virtual int getNo() { return m_fd; }
};

enum EListenFlags {
   E_LISTEN_READ = 1,
   E_LISTEN_WRITE = 2,
   E_LISTEN_ERROR = 4,
   E_LISTEN_NONBLOCK = 8
};

class AsyncDescriptor : public Descriptor {
// like EPoll (for linux) or IOCP (for Windows) or SELECT, POLL...
public:
   virtual bool listen(Descriptor* pDesc, int listenFlags) = 0;
   virtual bool dizzy(Descriptor* pDesc, int dizzyFlags) = 0;
   virtual bool wait(std::list<Descriptor*>& listOut) = 0;
   virtual bool list(std::list<Descriptor*>& listOut) = 0;
   virtual bool getFlags(Descriptor* pDesc, int* flagOutput) = 0;
};

class SocketDescriptor : public Descriptor {
     // Omitted.......
};

// Details are omitted below ...
```

How can i implement it???! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that (getting a non-OS specific file descriptor, or portably dealing with network sockets without any OS support). [File descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) & [network sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) are an [Operating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific thing (or in the POSIX standard). The 
[C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (from [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standards) does not know them. [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) is [POSIX 2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fileno.html) (and also in POSIX 2008).

If coding in C++, you might use framework libraries like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) (or perhaps [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)) wrapping some OS services (e.g. for Linux, MacOSX, Windows, Android) and providing you with some unified abstractions. If coding in C, you could consider [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) and/or [Gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) (from GNOME/GTK).

BTW, you want some multiplexing ability (like the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) syscall provides on Linux & POSIX), and it is operating system specific. You could also consider using some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) library, like e.g. [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) or [libevent](http://libevent.org/) (or use the event loop facilities from Qt, from POCO, from GTK or Glib)

Notice that C & C++ are different languages, and both can exist on implementations without any networking facilities (e.g. computers without network abilities, embedded systems, etc...).

Comment: thanks, but i want to encapsulate or abstract it. if the OS does not supports it, i want to implement it in user-space...! :) to create a new library for general-abstraction...

Comment: You *need* OS support. Just use some event loop library, as I mentioned. Or lose your time to re-implement your own (which would be more buggy). Better to use existing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Asio? Does it not do what you want to do?

https://think-async.com/